# Get old data from firebase when local user is deleted

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im working on a android app with email-password login.
The user is created in a local sqlite db and in firebase + auth.

**Situation**: The user uninstalls the app, the local db is deleted. Then the user re-installs the app and wants to login using old credentials, But the user does not exist locally thus the app tries to create a new. - but the user already exist remote in my firebase users table + auth.

**Question**: How do I query either **firebase auth** or **firebase** for the user info only using email, pass and perhaps a few extras.

Most answers I found refer to using the update event from firebase, but at this point it´s not possible as the user is not yet authenticated

Comment: Why do you create a user locally AND on Firebase ? Why isn't Firebase sufficient  ?

Comment: Can you show a piece of code that interacts with the Firebase API and highlights where you got stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

It was simple and not at all. A part of my fix is below. But in short. I get the user from firebase, then make an update to firebase and then I restore the user in a addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()

```
_fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Firebase login success");

        FirebaseUser fbUser = _fbAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid = fbUser.getUid();

        FireBaseWriteHelper wh = new FireBaseWriteHelper();
        FireBaseReadHelper fireBaseReadHelper = new FireBaseReadHelper(getApplicationContext(), uid, Util.VERSION_KEY_FREE);

        DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        wh.UpdateUserLastLogIn(uid, format.format(date));

        _user = _userHelper.CheckUserExist(_email, _password);

        mPasswordView.setError(null);
        mEmailView.setError(null);

    } else {
        try {
            throw task.getException();
        } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {
        } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
        } catch (FirebaseNetworkException e) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firebase in Offline mode. You don't need to use two databases. 
Guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).